# What does "He's a lox" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed (2006)*, Frank speaks on phone with Colin, who just saw
dead bodies of two gentlemen from Providence:

> Frank Costello: Who's the lead detective? Good. He's a **lox**.

By google, it is a reference to smoked salmon (lox). I am confused.

What does "He's a lox" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does "He's a lox" mean?

It means that he's not very aware of what's going on; that he's an easy target and/or is a sucker. Saying someone is a lox is another way of saying they're a fish -- a derogatory term that's commonly used in other contexts like poker games.

It comes from the whole, "fish vs. shark", dynamic...

Comment: It comes from the [Russian лохъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85#Russian) and is prison slang. Nothing to do with fish as far as I can tell (my Russian is quite rusty).

Answer (score 1):

Lox is [slang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%AC%D5%B8%D5%AD#:%7E:text=%D5%AC%D5%B8%D5%AD%20%E2%80%A2%20(lox),(slang)%20simpleton%2C%20dummy) for a

> "simpleton [or] dummy"

It may interest you that in [the original script](https://indiegroundfilms.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/departed-the-sept-06.pdf) he was described with a different word.

> **COSTELLO** *Who's the lead detective?... Good, **he's a moron.***